# How can I send to back an element in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to send an element behind all of the elements.
I tried to use Z-Index but it did not work because I need to send it behind all of the elements and I don't know how many are they(elements can increase by user);
pls help.

Comment: Maybe use `Int.MaxValue`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to do this in code, that you want to place a new element (in my example, a `Label`) "behind".

The way to do this is to replace the current `Content` of your control/window with a `Grid`, and then place your element in it together with the current content.

```cs
void PlaceLabelBehindEverything()
{
    var newLabel = new Label() { Content = "My Label that is behind everything" };
    var currentContent = this.Content; // assuming this method is in the control/window

    var grid = new Grid();
    this.Content = grid;
    
    grid.Children.Add(newLabel);
    grid.Children.Add(currentContent);
{
```

Comment: That was helpful , but not for my project:( I am working on a Training project that has drag and drop option. User can drop shapes and images on the page. I want to add an option that user could send an object behind of all objects(send to back option.)